# KineticJS appears to be clearing things from the canvas which I don't want to be cleared

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a web page with an HTML5 canvas, on which I'm displaying a few images, as well as some text and shapes.

The text and shapes have been drawn by the JavaScript functions:

```
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 950, 15);
}
```

and

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(){
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
    context.font = '25pt Calibri';
    context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
    context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);
}
```

The images are loaded from their sources into a hidden section in the HTML first, and then loaded from there into a JavaScript array called 'sources':

```
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var imagesDir = "";
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    //console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (var src in sources){
        numImages++;
    }
    //console.log("Num Images " + numImages);

    var index=0;
    console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("images array length = " + images.length);
    }

    stage.add(imagesLayer); // should only be added once!!
    drawGameElements();
}
```

After that, I then use another JS function to draw those images to the canvas:

```
function drawImage(imageObj) {
    //var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
  }
```

This function uses the KineticJS library to make the images draggable. When viewing the page in a browser, everything is initially displayed as intended, with the images, text and shapes all visible. However, as soon as you click on an image to drag and drop it around the canvas, the text and shapes that were drawn by standard JS functions (not the KineticJS library) all disappear from the canvas.

I assume this is because the KineticJS library clears the canvas completely when redrawing the images in a new location.

How can I ensure that the text and other shapes that I've also drawn to the canvas remain on the canvas when dragging and dropping the images? Or at least that they're redrawn along with the images on drag and drop?

Comment: Just make the description areas kinetic shapes with custom `drawFunc`.

Answer (score -1):

If you already use Kineticjs why don't ju just let Kineticjs draw the images and text at the beginning?

```
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 950, 15);
}
```

is easaly converted to a custom shape in Kineticjs and so is the things un your drawDescriptionBoxes function.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant and inappropriate. It isn't answering the OP's question at all. As it happens, I have a similar problem as the OP and I am using KineticJS exclusively for shape drawing.